# Clarifications about the correct way to solve exercises (continuity, partial derivatives, differentiability)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

I need some clarifications about the correct way to solve an exercise.

I have this function:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{(x-1)y^2}{\sin^2\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}$$

and I have to

1. analyse the existence of partial derivatives and the differentiability in (1,0)
2. say if f is differentiable in (0,0)

**About point 1**:
I have this doubt. Do I have to calculate the partial derivatives considering the expression of g(x,y) in (1,0) (i.e. g(1,0)=0 -> $\displaystyle {\partial f}/\partial x=\partial 0 / \partial x=0={\partial f}/\partial y $ (*) or do I have to use

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(1,0)=\lim_{t->0} \frac{f(1+t,0)-g(1,0)}{t}$ ? (**) Or do I have to find the expressions of the partial derivatives without using the limit and *then* do the limit for (x,y)->(1,0)?

If I want to analyse if $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(1,0)$ is continue, do I have to compare (*) and (**)?

**About point 2**:
If a function has continue partial derivatives in a point, it is differentiable in that point.

So I have thought that in Dom f, the partial derivatives are continue because thay're composition of continue function. Since $0 \in Dom f$, g(x,y) is differentiable in (0,0).

Is this reasoning ok, or do I have to check with calculation?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

1) If you take polar coordinates you get immediatly $$\lim_{\rho\rightarrow0^{+}}\frac{\rho^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)\left(\rho\cos\left(\theta\right)-1\right)}{\sin^{2}\left(\sqrt{\rho^{2}-2\rho\cos\theta+1}\right)}=0.
 $$ 2) See Dr. MV answer.

3) A function is differentiable in a point $\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)
 $ if the partials derivative exist in that point and if $$\lim_{\left(h,k\right)\rightarrow\left(0,0\right)}\frac{f\left(x_{0}+h,y_{0}+k\right)-f\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)h-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)k}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}}=0.
 $$

Comment: My question is about the correct way to find the expression of ∂f/∂x, ∂f/∂y... do I have to use the definition of the partial derivative or do I have to calculate the derivative respect with x considering y constant and *then* do the limit for (x,y)->(1,0)?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, in the definition of differentiability (h, k)->(0,0).. aren't they?

Comment: @sunrise There was a typo, thank you. You have to calculate the derivative and then the limit.

Comment: and then do I have to compare the limit with the value of the derivative in (1,0)? (g(1,0)=0 -> $\displaystyle {\partial f}/\partial x=\partial 0 / \partial x=0={\partial f}/\partial y $ )

Comment: It is not true that if $f\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)=0$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)=0.$ In this case you can't calculated the derivatives in $(1,0)$ because that point is a zero of the denominator. You can only take the limit.

Comment: Actually, the existence of the limit of the partial derivatives is not the same as the existence of the partial derivatives. Their equality (or lack thereof) would imply the stronger continuous partial derivatives (or not).  Otherwise, good answer.  I also like to use polar coordinates.  It's a powerful way forward for many applications and +1 for showing that here.  I would suggest that you fix the other issue.

Comment: @Dr.MV You're right, thank you and +1!

Comment: You're welcome!  +1 back!

Answer (score 2):

As shown by Marco Cantarin, we have that $f$ has a removable discontinuity at $(1,0)$ and we may define a new function, say, $\bar f$, that is equal to $f$ for $(x,y)\ne (1,0)$ and equal to $1$ for $(x,y)=(1,0)$.

Now, let's analyze the partial derivatives at $(1,0)$.  To that end, we use the definition of the first partial derivatives to expose that

$$\bar f_x(1,0)=\lim_{h\to 1}\frac{\bar f(1+h,0)-\bar f(1,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 1}\frac{0-0}{h}=0$$

$$\bar f_y(1,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\bar f(1,h)-\bar f(1,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 1}\frac{0-0}{h}=0$$

To show differentiability at $(1,0)$ we see that

$$\begin{align}
\bar f'(1,0) &\equiv \lim_{(h,k)\to (1,0)}\frac{\bar f(1+h,k)-\bar f(1,0)-\bar f_x(1,0)h-\bar f_y(1,0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\\\\
&=\lim_{(h,k)\to (1,0)}\frac{\frac{hk^2}{\sin \sqrt{h^2+k^2}}-0-0\cdot h-0\cdot k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\\\\
&=\lim_{(h,k)\to (1,0)}\frac{hk^2}{h^2+k^2}\cdot \lim_{(h,k)\to (1,0)}\frac{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}{\sin \sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\\\\
&=\lim_{(h,k)\to (1,0)}\frac{hk^2}{h^2+k^2}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

since

$$\frac{hk^2}{h^2+k^2}\le \frac{h(h^2+k^2)}{h^2+k^2}=h$$

Thus, $f$ is indeed differentiable at $(1,0)$!

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! But I'm interested to know if partial derivatives are continue in (1,0).. In which way can I check it? Do I have to compare the values that you have found $\bar f_x(1,0)$ and $\bar f_y(1,0)$ with the ∂0/∂x=0=∂f/∂y? ($\bar f (1,0)=0$, so if I derive it respect with x and y I obtain 0...) Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  To see if the partials are continous, find the general form and take the limit as $(x,y) \to (1,0)$.

Comment: and, if the partials are continuos, the limits must be equal to zero, aren't they?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly correct!!

Comment: Just a little clarification. They must be 0 because the limits that you have calculated are equal to zero or because $\bar f (1,0)=0$ and, if I derive it respect with x and y, I obtain 0?

Comment: The only limit I calculated was for $f'$.  This showed that $f$ is differentiable at $(1,0)$, but it does not imply that the first partial derivatives are continuous there.  You have to show that by taking a limit of the partials as $(x,y)\to (1,0)$